# Character vector in R as itemized list with knitr

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I have a vector (e.g. `letters`) that I want to incorporate into my `.Rnw` knitr document as an itemized list. How do I do this?

I have tried `\Sexpr{letters}` but it merely places commas between each:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z
```

Something like this is just as unhelpful:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item[\Sexpr{letters}]
\end{itemize}
```

What is the proper way to do this?

I'm looking for a result like:

- a
- b
- c
- d
- e
- f

etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item
<<results="asis", echo=FALSE>>=
  lets = letters[1:5]
  cat(lets, sep="\n\\item ")
@
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Or, more elegantly, with a dummy entry instead of the explicit `\item`:

```
<<results="asis", echo=FALSE>>=
  lets = letters[1:5]
  cat("", lets, sep="\n\\item ")
@
```

Answer (score 4):

Or

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

Here is a list.

\begin{itemize}
<<results="asis", echo=FALSE>>=
cat(sprintf('\\item{%s}', letters[1:5]), sep = '\n')
@
\end{itemize}

That was a list.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the character vector in code block as follows to knit to PDF format (logn strings automatically wrap to next lines, `'\n'` ensures correct formatting of bullet points:

```
---
title: "Bullet from string"
author: "author"
date: '2022-06-22'
output: pdf_document
---
```

Blabla... here your bullet list comes:

````
```{r mwe, include=TRUE, results = 'asis'}
str_example <- c(
 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'
  )
str_example <- paste0('* ', str_example, '\n')
cat(str_example)
```
````

[image]