# LaTeX {itemize} in R Markdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

How do I include the following LaTeX `{itemize}` in my R Markdown? It simply doesn't work when I try and knitr the HTML.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "March 2019"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

\[x = R + E\]
where:
\begin{itemize}
\item[R=] is Racoon
\item[E=] is Elephant
\end{itemize}
````

Comment: [This could help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29656476/1315767)

Comment: Why not using pure markdown syntax? Just use `*` for every new entry. https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/rmarkdown-cheatsheet.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R Markdown doesn't use LaTeX when producing HTML.  The code you used would work if output was to `pdf_document`, but not to `html_document`.

If you really want the labelled list in HTML, you're going to have to insert HTML code, not LaTeX code.  I don't know if there's anything visually equivalent to LaTeX's `\item[R=]`, but you could do this, which is logically equivalent:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "March 2019"
output: html_document

---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

\[x = R + E\]
where:

<dl>
<dt>R=</dt>
<dd>is Racoon</dd>
<dt>E=</dt> 
<dd>is Elephant</dd>
</dl>
````

This displays as

[image: screenshot]

Perhaps CSS could be crafted to make it visually equivalent.

Edited to add:  And of course it is possible, and has been done.  It's easy to follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/13371522/2554330, since R Markdown uses the Bootstrap framework.  Just add a class to the first tag:

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
<dt>R=</dt>
<dd>is Racoon</dd>
<dt>E=</dt> 
<dd>is Elephant</dd>
</dl>
```

and it produces

[image: another screenshot]

If the styling is still not satisfactory, look at some of the other discussion related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/13371522/2554330.

Answer (score 3):

Just use either + or - at the beginning of sentences which you wish to itemize, it works for both html and pdf output of Rmarkdown
eg
use the statement in between '$' symbol
$+ this statement will be itemized in rmd$